# How to lower the Java Security setting for testing in Java 8

Tags: java, security

I'm testing my Java applet but with java 1.8 we can't lower the security setting below High which stops me from testing my applet.

I'm mainly looking for a way to lower this but I'm also accepting a way to make it acceptable by Java 8 standards.

Comment: An applet? In 2015? You should consider at least using JNLP instead; and anyway, without proper signing, you won't be able to run it on any client machine

Comment: That's not the current objective, i just want to be able to test it in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add your link in the exceptions list. Medium security setting that allowed content without certificate was removed after java 8 update 20