# How to send JavaScript Variables to a Matlab Simulink UDP Block?

Tags: javascript, java, matlab, applet, udp

I'd like to send a few variables to a Matlab Simulink Model. I was planning on doing this via setting up a UDP Connection but I can't seem to find a way to do this via JavaScript directly. So the idea is to instead somehow send that data to a Java Applet or Python server or something. Then use that to configure the connection and send that to the Matlab UDP Receive block (more details [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/udpreceive.html)).

The question is I'm not sure how to send that data to the Java or Python Server.  Also I couldn't get a Java Applet to actually run on the webpage due to security settings despite looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336132/how-to-lower-the-java-security-setting-for-testing-in-java-8) to change the exception list. Apparently applets are also a bit dated too I saw a few things about JNLP. I'm not sure if that's the way to go or not.

Essentially all I need is some code that I can call via JavaScript and send variables to.

I realize this is a very open ended question, but I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Comment: Javascript can communicate over HTTP, HTTPS and WebSockets which are TCP protocols and no UDP protocols. You should write a simple Python script for example to send UDP packets: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication
Btw, Java has not much to do with JavaScript.

Comment: *"..send that data to a Java Applet.."* See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: "Apparently applets are also a bit dated too I saw a few things about JNLP. I'm not sure if that's the way to go or not."... I'm guessing the way to go is via ajax after further googling.